# Rails form not retaining values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a field in one of my Rails forms that selects a "unit" and works fine initially.  However when I go into the record the select defaults to another unit and not the one that was assigned, thus not retaining the value.

```
_form.html.erb
<%= f.select :unit_id, options_for_select(unit_select), {}, {:class => 'select'} %>  

helper
def unit_select
    Unit.all.map{|unit| unit.calls.empty? ? [unit.unit_name, unit.id] : ["#{unit.unit_name} (on call)", unit.id] }
  end
```

The only thing I can think of is it's not retaining the value since the form field is using a map.  I'm kind of newish to Rails and Ruby so I don't fully understand the constrains of my code yet.

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by using options_for_select :selected => @call.unit.id

It then retained the previous selected value.